# Cannot mount /dev/sda6 after upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, mount, fstab, exfat

I have accidentally upgraded my system from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. Everything was working fine, but from recently I cannot mount /dev/sda6 partition (exFAT) anymore. After running:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /media/zorz/Data/
```

I receive a following error:

```
mount: according to mtab, `/dev/sda6` is already mounted on /media/zorz/Data
```

If I try to do it by click, the more detailed error appears:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda6 at /media/zorz/Data: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sda6" "/media/zorz/Data"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:
stdout: `FUSE exfat 1.2.3
'
stderr: `mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda6 is already mounted on /media/zorz/Data

'
```

Basically, any directory that I make under e.g. `/media/zorz/test3`, I get the similar error, but this time it ends with the `test3`:

```
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda6 is already mounted on /media/zorz/test3
```

This partition is used for executing files and running scripts, and it was accessible by both Ubuntu and Windows 10, since I've been running dual boot for a few years so far. I'm not sure if this error is a result of an upgrade, but I remember that after the upgrade, the system was restarted without unmounting it previously. Usually if that happens, I would just receive a warning that `sda6` was not unmounted cleanly.
I have already tried the prescriptions from other similar problems, but with no success. Are there any other suggestions of what I could check in order for this to work? As a final resort, I would do a clean install.

(Updated for the solutions proposed in comments)
Folder `/media/zorz/Data/` is an empty folder. If I click on the partition in Nautilus, as suggested, again I obtain the same error.
exfat support was updated just before posting this, but still nothing improved, the error persists.

`umount`

```
zorz@zorz-LIFEBOOK-E554:~$ sudo umount /media/zorz/Data
umount: /media/zorz/Data: not mounted

zorz@zorz-LIFEBOOK-E554:~$ sudo umount /dev/sda6
umount: /dev/sda6: not mounted
```

In `fstab` and `mtab`, there are no references to sda6. The command `mount -a` gives no output. The output for `mount`,`udisks --dump` and `lsblk` contains the following:

`fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=527ea26f-c915-47a9-af81-248d56f41b9d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=4CF8-0068  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=4c6dc5ae-7633-4913-bfce-c0c4cb724c0c none            swap    sw              0       0
```

`mtab`

```
/dev/sda2 /boot/efi vfat rw 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
systemd /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd 0 0
```

`mount`

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=6082360k,nr_inodes=1520590,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1219396k,mode=755)
/dev/sda8 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=4k,mode=755)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,relatime)
none on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,relatime)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=102400k,mode=755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda2 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

`udisks --dump`

```
========================================================================
Showing information for /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda6
  native-path:                 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata5/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sda/sda6
  device:                      8:6
  device-file:                 /dev/sda6
    presentation:              /dev/sda6
    by-id:                     /dev/disk/by-id/ata-TOSHIBA_MQ01ABF050_85TKC1GHT-part6
    by-id:                     /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000039673c8afb8-part6
    by-id:                     /dev/disk/by-uuid/5A82-0E81
    by-path:                   /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1f.2-ata-5-part6
  detected at:                 Fri 31 Jan 2020 01:14:53 AM CET
  system internal:             1
  removable:                   0
  has media:                   1 (detected at Fri 31 Jan 2020 01:14:53 AM CET)
    detects change:            0
    detection by polling:      0
    detection inhibitable:     0
    detection inhibited:       0
  is read only:                0
  is mounted:                  0
  mount paths:             
  mounted by uid:              0
  presentation hide:           0
  presentation nopolicy:       0
  presentation name:           
  presentation icon:           
  automount hint:              
  size:                        107374182400
  block size:                  512
  job underway:                no
  usage:                       filesystem
  type:                        exfat
  version:                     1.0
  uuid:                        5A82-0E81
  label:                       Data
  partition:
    part of:                   /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda
    scheme:                    gpt
    number:                    6
    type:                      EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
    flags:                    
    offset:                    149622358016
    alignment offset:          0
    size:                      107374182400
    label:                     Basic data partition
    uuid:                      0636A8B6-8189-400C-B410-4EA200FC4B70

========================================================================
```

`lsblk`

```
zorz@zorz-LIFEBOOK-E554:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0  57.2G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0    80G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0   100G  0 part 
├─sda7   8:7    0    15G  0 part 
├─sda8   8:8    0 205.5G  0 part /
└─sda9   8:9    0   5.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: @mchid Thanks for the suggestions. I have updated the post with the info you suggested, but still no improvements...

Comment: Cool, thanks. I think I found the problem. 16.04 uses a symlink for `/etc/mtab` instead of a file. Although use of a file is said to still be supported, creating a symlink is supposed to resolve many bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mtab file looks incomplete. There have been bugs filed by people who upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and it looks like mtab might not get updated properly using the 14.04 setup.

Comparing the [mount manpage for 14.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/mount.8.html) and the [mount manpage for 16.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mount.8.html) reveals that there  was a change to the `/etc/mtab` file.

14.04, uses a "real mtab file" whereas 16.04 uses a symlink to `/proc/mounts` or `/proc/self/mounts`.

First, backup your existing `mtab` file by running the following command:

```
sudo cp /etc/mtab /etc/mtabbackup
```

Then, create the symlink to `/proc/self/mounts` by running the following command (make sure to copy and paste this or **make sure not to reverse the order here as this is important!**):

```
sudo ln -fs /proc/self/mounts /etc/mtab
```

Now, you can either see if you can mount or unmount the partition or reboot and try again.

Comment: Works like a charm! After following the instructions, there was no need to reboot, and   `sda6` is finally mounted. File `/etc/mtab` now ends with `/dev/sda6 /media/zorz/Data fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0`